# Loading composer from template and generating atlas using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, print-composer, qgis-2

I am trying to build a plugin to load a print composer from file, generate an atlas and export to image. So far I have been successful in loading the template and exporting it to image.

I have been unable to add any of the layers in the legend (which are also in the toc) to the exported map, which results in a blank map and none of the field expressions working.

```
    # Get layers in the legend and append, suspect there must be a cleaner way to do this
    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layerStringList = []
    for layer in layers:
        layerID = layer.id()
        layerStringList.append(layerID)

    # Add layer to map render
    myMapRenderer = QgsMapRenderer()
    myMapRenderer.setLayerSet(layerStringList)
    myMapRenderer.setProjectionsEnabled(False)

    # Load template
    myComposition = QgsComposition(myMapRenderer)
    myFile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'MMR_Template.qpt')
    myTemplateFile = file(myFile, 'rt')
    myTemplateContent = myTemplateFile.read()
    myTemplateFile.close()
    myDocument = QDomDocument()
    myDocument.setContent(myTemplateContent)
    myComposition.loadFromTemplate(myDocument)

    # Save image
    myImagePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'come_on.png')
    myImage = myComposition.printPageAsRaster(0)
    myImage.save(myImagePath)
```

Here is a snippet from the loaded template which should setup the atlas:

```
 <Atlas hideCoverage="false" featureFilter="reference = '61922'"    coverageLayer="desktop_search20130615160118593" fixedScale="true" composerMap="0" singleFile="false" filenamePattern="&quot;reference&quot;" enabled="true" filterFeatures="true" sortFeatures="true" sortKey="0" sortAscending="true" margin="1"/>
```

I am also unsure of the best way to add all the layer in the toc to the instance of QgsMapRenderer().

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If anyone is interested here is the code I ended up with. This will turn on/off specific layers in the table of contents (from a list of layers), load a selected composer template from file, generate an atlas and export the map. Finally, returning the table of contents to its original state.

```
def sort_toc(self):

    # Turn on/off layers as required by search type
    legend = self.iface.legendInterface()
    layers = legend.layers()
    wanted_layers = metal_wanted
    global turn_on, turn_off, atlas_desktop
    turn_off = []
    turn_on = []
    all_layers = []
    for layer in layers:
        layername = layer.name()
        all_layers.append(layername)
        layerid = layer.id()
        if layername == "desktop_search":
            atlas_desktop = layer
        if layername in wanted_layers and legend.isLayerVisible(layer) is False:
            turn_off.append(layer)
            legend.setLayerVisible(layer, True)
        if layername not in wanted_layers and legend.isLayerVisible(layer) is True:
            turn_on.append(layer)
            legend.setLayerVisible(layer, False)
        else:
            pass

    # Checks for required layers missing from map file
    for layer in wanted_layers:
        missing = []
        if layer not in all_layers:
            missing.append(layer)
        else:
            pass
    if not missing:
        pass
    else:
        QMessageBox.warning(self.iface.mainWindow(), "Missing layers", "Required layers are missing from your map file. Details: %s" % (str(missing)))
    return atlas_desktop

def quick_export(self, ref, stype, scale):

    # Add all layers in map canvas to render
    myMapRenderer = self.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()

    # Load template from file
    myComposition = QgsComposition(myMapRenderer)
    myFile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'MMR_Template.qpt')
    myTemplateFile = file(myFile, 'rt')
    myTemplateContent = myTemplateFile.read()
    myTemplateFile.close()
    myDocument = QDomDocument()
    myDocument.setContent(myTemplateContent)
    myComposition.loadFromTemplate(myDocument)

    # Get map composition and define scale
    myAtlasMap = myComposition.getComposerMapById(0)
    myAtlasMap.setNewScale(int(scale))

    # Setup Atlas
    myAtlas = QgsAtlasComposition(myComposition)
    myAtlas.setCoverageLayer(atlas_desktop) # Atlas run from desktop_search
    myAtlas.setComposerMap(myAtlasMap)
    myAtlas.setFixedScale(True)
    myAtlas.fixedScale()
    myAtlas.setHideCoverage(False)
    myAtlas.setFilterFeatures(True)
    myAtlas.setFeatureFilter("reference = '%s'" % (str(ref)))
    myAtlas.setFilterFeatures(True)

    # Generate atlas
    myAtlas.beginRender()
    for i in range(0, myAtlas.numFeatures()):
        myAtlas.prepareForFeature( i )
        jobs = r"\\MSUKSERVER\BusinessMan Docs\Jobs"
        job_fol = os.path.join(jobs, str(ref))
        output_jpeg = os.path.join(job_fol, ref + "_BMS_plan.jpg")
        myImage = myComposition.printPageAsRaster(0)
        myImage.save(output_jpeg)
    myAtlas.endRender()

def return_toc(self):

    # Revert layers back to pre-script state (on/off)
    legend = self.iface.legendInterface()
    for wanted in turn_on:
        legend.setLayerVisible(wanted, True)
    for unwanted in turn_off:
        legend.setLayerVisible(unwanted, False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this can work on you for getting all current layers:

```
registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
layers = registry.mapLayers().values()
```