# Programmatically export a Qgis project

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have a QGis project that I programmatically modify using the Python xml.etree library. 
Now, I would like to know if it is possible to add few lines to my script in order to export the modified project to a new jpg image. The python script should be run OUTSIDE the QGis python console. Thanks!

Comment: Export image from composer or data view?

Comment: Export from composer, with map, title, labels, tables, logos... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `printPageAsRaster (int page)` function from the [QgsComposition](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsComposition.html) class

> print composer page to image If the image does not fit into memory, a
>   null image is returned More...

This Q/A gives an example of it exporting to png (which you can change to jpg).

[Programmatically load composer from template and generate atlas using pyQgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77848/programmatically-load-composer-from-template-and-generate-atlas-using-pyqgis)