# QGIS Default Map Composer On Open

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing, mapping, user-interface

Is there a way to to have a map (Print Composer) open automatically upon project load?

I have a map constructed in Print Composer "General Map".

When a user fires off the project, I would like "General Map" to open by default.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any way to designate the print composer to open as a default action of the QGIS software. Also, I'm not sure if there is a plug-in either, I would imagine if there was this capability available it would be available as a plug-in unless the QGIS developers move to having the print composer open as a default option.

Furthermore, I came across a discussion in a different [forum](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/default-print-template-td4980191.html) that discusses the thought process amongst some QGIS developers about the reason to not having this as a default option but rather encouraging users to utilize the template load option for customization of each print composer for a particular project.

Answer (score 2):

As @whyzar already mentioned, I don't think there's a setting or plugin which could achieve this directly (not yet anyway).

However, you can achieve this by using a **Python script inside a macro** (script adapted from [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77848/programmatically-load-composer-from-template-and-generate-atlas-using-pyqgis), credit to @Matt) which runs whenever the project is loaded. Note that the *Print composer template* must be saved separately as the following script loads this `.qpt` file:

```
import os, qgis
from PyQt4.QtXml import QDomDocument

# Change path and name of template accordingly
myFile = os.path.join('C:/Users/You/Desktop//', 'General Map.qpt')
myTemplateFile = file(myFile, 'rt')
myTemplateContent = myTemplateFile.read()
myTemplateFile.close()
myDocument = QDomDocument()
myDocument.setContent(myTemplateContent, False)
newcomp = qgis.utils.iface.createNewComposer()
newcomp.composition().loadFromTemplate(myDocument)
```

From the toolbar, insert the script in:

*Project > Project Properties... > Macros*

[image: Script to load composer template]

Make sure you do the following:

- Save your project
- Enable macros by going to:

  *Settings > Options > General > Project files*

  [image: Enable macros]

Now when the project is loaded, the composer template should pop up.

Comment: That is a neat script to make this feature available

Comment: @whyzar - Thank you buddy but the script has been mentioned in several posts such as [this one](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77848/programmatically-load-composer-from-template-and-generate-atlas-using-pyqgis) so I just _borrowed_ it ;)