# Why do I get a NameError for QDomDocument when attempting to programmatically load a template in the QGIS Python console?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2.14

I'm trying to work through [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/82181/36886) in the QGIS (2.14) Python console to understand, ultimately, [how to iterate over layers and print them with a template](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189735/how-to-iterate-over-layers-and-export-them-as-png-images-with-pyqgis-in-a-standa).

When I run the following code block.

I get a NameError that QDomDocument() is undefined.

```
myComposition = QgsComposition(myMapRenderer)
myFile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'MMR_Template.qpt')
myTemplateFile = file(myFile, 'rt')
myTemplateContent = myTemplateFile.read()
myTemplateFile.close()
myDocument = QDomDocument()
```

Possibly related (can split into a separate question) I also get the warning `DeprecationWarning: QgsComposition constructor is deprecated` but can find nothing about this warning on Google.

Comment: did you add `from qgis.PyQt.QtXml import QDomDocument`

Comment: Nope. Will try tomorrow

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn that worked. Any idea about the deprecation warning?

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn feel free to turn your comment into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221580/why-do-i-get-a-nameerror-for-qdomdocument-when-attempting-to-programmatically-lo?noredirect=1#comment341442_221580), adding the following line to the console script resolved this issue in `2.14` to `2.18.2`

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtXml import QDomDocument
```