# Expression-based labels in scripted Atlas fail to update

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, atlas

I try to follow [Programmatically load composer from template and generate atlas using pyQgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77848) to automate atlas print composer using pyqgis :

specific in atlas code say :

```
    myAtlasMap = myComposition.getComposerMapById(0)
    myAtlas = QgsAtlasComposition(myComposition)
    myAtlas.setCoverageLayer(atlas_desktop)
    myAtlas.setComposerMap(myAtlasMap)
    myAtlas.setFixedScale(True)
    myAtlas.fixedScale()
    myAtlas.setHideCoverage(False)
    myAtlas.setFilterFeatures(True)
```

this code work for my task and i take new 100 atlas feutures maps but in my `template.qpt` i have some labels with code like this :

`QGIS [%concat( "OBJECTID" )%]`

that `OBJECTID` is the same for all new 100 atlas feutures maps.
Any idea why? If I use manual atlas export, then for any map `OBJECTID` change.

---

I have more details the true Does not work anything related to layer atlas in my `template.qpt` i have some base styles rules or base labels rules like this :

```
intersects($atlasgeometry, $geometry )
```

or

```
$id = $atlasfeatureid
```

that is the some in 100 maps :

[image: label]

i think so that [Programmatically load composer from template and generate atlas using pyQgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77848) just export one by one my features from my atlas layer and the atlas in my template stay False.

any idea ?

Comment: If you are still interested in solving this problem, please can you post the code you are using to render the atlas?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to test without a demo.

What happens if you are more explicit in the label so:

```
QGIS [% concat( attribute(  @atlas_feature , 'OBJECTID'))% ]
```