# PyQGIS/QGIS2.18 : Get currently active map tool

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2.18, maptools

I would like to get the name of the map tool currently in use in QGIS, so that my plugin can react accordingly. The idea would be to do something a bit like [akbargumbira's answer to that other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77848/programmatically-load-composer-from-template-and-generate-atlas-using-pyqgis), but for map tools instead of map layers. It should look like that :

```
if QGisMapTool.instance().value()=="Identify":
    do something
elif QGisMapTool.instance().value()=="Measure":
    do something else
(...)
```

I've searched on Stack and in the API documentation, but I have been unable to find the appropriate method so far.

Comment: you can use `iface.mapCanvas().mapTool().toolName ()` for obtain the current maptool name .https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapTool.html

Comment: *facepalm* I ctrl+F'ed the page you link for "value", "instance", "attribute", "object" but not for "name". My mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One issue with trying to get the name of the tool is that not all tools have a name to begin with. For example, when using the **Select Feature(s)** tool, it's tool name is:

```
iface.mapCanvas().mapTool().toolName()
>>> u'Select features'
```

But when using the **Select Features by Polygon**:

```
iface.mapCanvas().mapTool().toolName()
>>> u''
```

Some tools don't have an individual name.

---

One method is to instead get the **class** of the current map tool and use this in an `if` statement:

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapTool, QgsMapToolIdentify

if isinstance(iface.mapCanvas().mapTool(), QgsMapToolIdentify):
    # do something
elif isinstance(iface.mapCanvas().mapTool(), QgsMapTool):
    # do something
```

Note that all map canvas tools fall into the [QgsMapTool](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapTool.html) class (as mentioned by [@FranciscoRaga](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/49538/francisco-raga) and referenced in the image below). Therefore in the above code, if the first `if` statement is not true then it will pass to the `elif`.

[image: QgsMapTools]