# Loading .qgs and .qpt files in standalone PyQGIS script?

Tags: pyqgis, python-2.7, standalone

I have a `.qgs` and `.qpt` files. And I would like to know if it is possible to use them in a standalone PyQGIS script?

I am using QGIS 2.18 and Python 2.7

[image]
This is the template that I would like to use.

[image]
And put this image inside that template using python if that is possible. I'm nearly finished with my thesis and this is the only part that is holding me back.

Comment: https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsProject.html#ad31ea90fe02d7271c374c7816deb429c

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77848/programmatically-load-composer-from-template-and-generate-atlas-using-pyqgis/82181

Comment: thank you for the response. I will look into this tomorrow. But I have a question. the link that you sent. I saw that it utilizes iface. will that work in a standalone script?

Comment: No, that won't work, but you will also only need parts of the code there.

Comment: Can you give me an idea what parts are those? Thank you so much

Comment: add sample when you are loading a `.qgs` and `.qpt`

Comment: @FranRaga hello. what sample kind of sample? a script of loading .qgs and .qpt?