# Loading print layout using an existing template (.qpt) with PyQgis3

Tags: pyqgis-3, qgis-print-layouts

I'm trying to load a print layout (.qpt) which I saved earlier via PyQgis.

I found this earlier entry, but it's for QGIS 2.x and thus doesn't work for QGIS3:
[Programmatically load composer from template and generate atlas using pyQgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77848/programmatically-load-composer-from-template-and-generate-atlas-using-pyqgis)

Does anyone know how to do this in QGIS3?

Answer (score 7):

For load **qpt** in **QGIS 3** you need something like this:

```
# Load template from file
p = QgsProject()
l = QgsLayout(p)
tmpfile = 'D://temp//test.qpt'
with open(tmpfile) as f:
    template_content = f.read()
doc = QDomDocument()
doc.setContent(template_content)

# adding to existing items
items, ok = l.loadFromTemplate(doc, QgsReadWriteContext(), False)
```

look at the API [loadFromTemplate()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayout.html#ad84ff95e98598ed3c29eef973d7b4bff)

Comment: May need to use 'QgsPrintLayout' instead of 'QgsLayout' now (for some applications)